# Will Unity 2D hide the launcher when windows are maximized?

Tags: unity-2d

If *"One of the design goals of Unity is to reduce the clutter of the desktop, another is to use space more efficiently."* Then why not hide the multi-color launcher when your windows are maximized on a small laptop? So i can see it just when I'm going to use it.

The desktop looks very cool when applications are not maximized by the way :)

Answer (score 3):

This is now implemented in Unity 2D for Natty. I encourage you to try it out using our daily PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~unity-2d-team/+archive/unity-2d-daily

References:

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop)
- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: Just to complete the answer: This feature is NOT available for Ubuntu 10.10 (via PPA).

Answer (score 2):

gconf-editor > desktop > unity-2d > launcher> edit key from 0 to 1/2 and tick "use strut"

- [How do I use the gconf editor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it will It already does on the normal Unity its a compiz setting it has been stated that this and many other enhancements are to be ported to unity 2d