# Will Unity 2d top panel be theme-able and support transparency?

Tags: unity-2d

Does anyone knows if the 2D (Qt) version of unity will be theme-able and also will support transparency in the top panel?

How customizable is Unity 2D planned to be?

Answer (score 3):

Unity 2D is nearly not customizable at all for the moment. All customization that exists today is [through GConf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor) (/desktop/unity-2d key).
As of now, there is no plan to improve on that.

The top panel cannot be made transparent without compositing support. Metacity (used in Unity 2D) has support for compositing but it is not well tested and has a [list of known bugs](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=REOPENED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEEDINFO&field0-0-0=component&field1-0-0=product&query_format=advanced&type0-0-0=substring&type1-0-0=substring&value0-0-0=Iain%27s%20compositor&value1-0-0=metacity&order=bug_severity,bug_id%20DESC&query_based_on=).

Answer (score 0):

About the customization, OMG Ubuntu reported that there is a GUI tool for that:
["Ubuntu Unity 2d tweaking tool"](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/ubuntu-unity-2d-tweaking-tool-lets-you-adjust-the-launcher-dash-enable-compositing/), that allows the user to configure all the options possible at the moment.