# Keyboard shortcuts not working after removing Shutter

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gconf, screenshot, shutter

I installed [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) then removed it, and now <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> shortcuts are no longer triggering screenshots with gnome-screenshot. How do I restore this setting?

Comment: i tried a workaround: i reinstalled shutter then unchecked the key bindings there, then removed it. now at least i can use <kbd>Print</kbd>

Comment: This is a reported bug already in launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shutter/+bug/611495

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open gconf-editor and change the following keys back to this:

/apps/metacity/keybinding_commands/command_screenshot => `/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot`

/apps/metacity/keybinding_commands/command_window_screenshot => `/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot --window`

[image: gconf-editor edits being made]

If you don't have [gconf-editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gconf-editor) [image: Install gconf-editor] yet just install it from the software center.

- [How do I use the gconf editor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor)

Answer (score 2):

Go to System->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts and see if the entries for 'Take a screenshot' and 'Take a screenshot of a window' are present.

Also try

> > sudo apt-get remove --purge shutter

to remove any leftover configuration.