# Why isn't the Printscreen button working in Gnome?

Tags: gnome

Printscreen button not working on Gnome. I have to Run Shutter to make printscreen. Is there any tutorial to make it work with printscreen button?

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: This is the expected behavior with Shutter. It takes over the keybindings for Printscreen. See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30701/keyboard-shortcuts-not-working-after-removing-shutter) for how to switch it back.

Comment: no... when i click printscreen button, it does have sound like we take a shot, but nothing happen...

Comment: I installed Shutter as an option because Printscrint button not working. But with, Unity its works perfect!

Comment: You will need to go back and find out the underlying problem that caused your Printscreen button to stop working then. Installing Shutter only complicated the issue. Also, if it works fine with Unity and it's broken with Gnome 3, it's probably a bug to be filed with the Gnome 3 developers.

Comment: Alright then. I will report this as a bug...

Comment: I found this gnome-screenshot --interactive .

Comment: I experience the same behaviour. Yet it does not do nothing. You hear the sound, the monitor flashes and the screenshot is being saved in your Pictures-folder. Have you checked it if the screenshots appear there?

Comment: See [Where is the print screen dialogue?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/118573/where-is-the-print-screen-dialogue)

Comment: yes im very sure. It does hv sound but nothing happen after that. in picture forlder also emty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually it's working if you hear a sound. You screenshots are saved to the picture folder.

The Gnome guys changed the default behaviour, take a look at the [Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/927952) or at the upstream [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=669629) for more details.

Comment: I removed my Pictures folder...

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't work in Older Versions of Unity or gnome classic, try updating the kernel. What version are you using 12.10 or 12.04 11.10 11.04 Lucid Lynx? If you're using version 12.04 it's very simple http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4-precise/
and download the correct ones for you arch like AMD64 or i386 or ARMS. Install them by the terminal:

```
cd Downloads
sudo dpkg -i Linux*.deb
```

This will install all the files. This fixed many errors with my keyboard like the back-lit and NumLock and hr volume controls or try switching over to KDE Kubuntu it worked for me.

Comment: r00t@penreturns:~$ uname -m; uname -a; lsb_release -a
x86_64
Linux penreturns 3.2.0-25-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 20:30:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release: 12.04
Codename: precise
r00t@penreturns:~$

Comment: im not using kernel 3.4 ... my skype hang after upgrade, so i remain using kenel 3.2