# Where is the screenshot?

Tags: unity, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard shortcuts not working after removing Shutter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30701/keyboard-shortcuts-not-working-after-removing-shutter)

I pressed <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>, saw a flash and heard a shutter sound but no screenshot file saved in `~/Pictures`. However, if I take the screenshot via the terminal or using the gnome-screenhot GUI, a dialog box appears prompting me to choose a location to save the screenshot.

I am using Unity in Ubuntu 12.04. According to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/927952), a fix has been released for the no dialog box issue, but where is the fix? I see neither a dialog box nor the screen-shot.

- My system is completely up to date, I have activated even the pre-released and unsupported update repositories.

Comment: Would [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/114429/default-save-directory-for-gnome-screenshot) help?

Comment: Did you have another screenshot application installed before? The screen flash/shutter sound bit don't make sense but the [answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/42435/12864) describes how to check or restore default keybindings to `gnome-screenshot`. Can you check that they are correct?

Comment: Hi, Tom,

That was exactly my problem. I have installed and removed shutter and the solution in your link works completely. Thank you very much!!

P.S. I thought gconf-editor is no longer used, replaced by dconf-editor??

Comment: Someone should file a bug with shutter so that removing it doesn't break the other screenshot tool!