# Unable right click on Desktop Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, mouse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Right-clicking on the Unity desktop does nothing - ideas?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36512/right-clicking-on-the-unity-desktop-does-nothing-ideas)

After I installed the CCMM and I explored it. Finnaly my mouse unable to right click. Please give me solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Look for something related to locking your desktop. CCMM is not in front of me right now, hence I cant give the exact steps.