# Is there a way I can completely disable workspaces and remove the icon from my Unity-2D panel?

Tags: panel, unity-2d, workspaces

My system is built around my 71 year old father (who is a recent, and very supportive Linux user now).

He doesn't have any need for multiple desktops and I find that having too many things on the panel can be a bit confusing for him.

Is there any way to completely disable workspaces / as well as remove the icon from the panel?

Comment: Please vote for https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/997322

Answer (score 8):

1. Disabling multiple workspaces:

   - Using [GConf Editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor), change the value of the `/apps/metacity/general/num_workspaces` to `1`.
2. Removing the *Workspace Switcher* from the Launcher:

   > **Remove and Rearrange**
   >
   > So to make this changes you need to edit one file. 
   >   First to be safe make a backup:

(for 11.04 & 11.10)

> ```
> sudo cp /usr/share/unity-2d/launcher/Launcher.qml /usr/share/unity-2d/launcher/Launcher.qml-backup
> ```
>
> when you screw up something just:
>
> ```
> sudo cp /usr/share/unity-2d/launcher/Launcher.qml-backup /usr/share/unity-2d/launcher/Launcher.qml
> ```

(for 12.04)

> ```
> sudo cp /usr/share/unity-2d/shell/launcher/Launcher.qml /usr/share/unity-2d/shell/launcher/Launcher.qml-backup
> ```
>
> when you screw up something just:
>
> ```
> sudo cp /usr/share/unity-2d/launcher/Launcher.qml-backup /usr/share/unity-2d/launcher/Launcher.qml
> ```
>
> Now for removing items from the Launcher:

(for 11.04/11.10):

> ```
> gksu gedit /usr/share/unity-2d/launcher/Launcher.qml
> ```
>
> scroll down to line 104, there you will see:

(for 12.04)

> ```
> gksu gedit /usr/share/unity-2d/shell/launcher/Launcher.qml
> ```
>
> scroll down to line 104, there you will see:
>
> ```
> Component.onCompleted: {
>     items.appendModel(applications);
>     items.appendModel(workspaces);
>     items.appendModel(visiblePlaces);
>     items.appendModel(devices);
>     shelfItems.appendModel(trashes);
> ```
>
> `items.appendModel(applications);` = applications in launcher
>   **`items.appendModel(workspaces);` = Workspace Switcher**
>   `items.appendModel(visiblePlaces);` = Files & Folders and application   `button.items.appendModel(devices);` = mounted drives (NTFS) + flash drives etc.
>   `shelfitems.appendModel(trashes);` = Trash
>
> You can remove these items by deleting their lines or you can rearrange items by moving lines up or down.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://www.ubunturoot.com/2011/02/remove-and-rearrange-items-in-unity-2d.html)</sup>

It should be noted that the second step is editing actual code and not a configuration file and thus any changes will be overwritten the next time you install a `unity-2d` update.

Answer (score 4):

Great answer above by the way.  Thank you.  To simplify things a bit you can reduce the workspaces from the terminal by:

```
    gconftool-2 -s /apps/metacity/general/num_workspaces --type int 1
```

and alter the configuration (remove the workspace launcher from the Launcher by:)

```
    sudo cp /usr/share/unity-2d/launcher/Launcher.qml{,.bck}
    sudo sed -i '/items.appendModel(workspaces)/d' /usr/share/unity-2d/launcher/Launcher.qml
```

Yes this will get reset anytime that the package unity-2d-launcher gets updated.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier workaround now, as described in [the bug regarding this issue in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/997322) (thanks to @Romanlvanov for the link by the way)

As explained by [Jon Hanna](https://launchpad.net/~jonhanna) in that bug:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Restart the system and open `ccsm`, go to `Ubuntu Unity Plugin` switch to the `Experimental` tab and turn off `Show "Expo Icon" in the launcher`.