# Nautilus missing toolbar, stuck in text-only "location bar" mode after 11.10 upgrade

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

After upgrading to 11.10, Nautilus is only giving me a text-only location box to select files. How can I get the toolbar (with the "up to parent", "home", etc buttons) back? Or failing that, is there a way to switch to breadcrumb mode?

I have already tried changing my gconf preferences for nautilus -- `always_use_location_entry` and `start_with_location_bar` are disabled, and `start_with_toolbar` is enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nautilus no longer uses [GConf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor) to store its settings, it instead uses the newer [DConf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-and-what-is-its-function).

To edit DConf settings install the [dconf-tools[image: Install dconf-tools]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) package and then open *dconf 
Editor*:

[image]
The key you are looking for is *org ➜ gnome ➜ nautilus ➜ preferences ➜ always-use-location-entry*. Make sure it is unchecked:

[image]

Comment: The bug for this missing button when always-use-location-entry is true is filed here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=662243

Answer (score 1):

I set **always-use-location-entry** to **false** in `dconf-editor` and the location entry still persists. I got no bread crumb buttons.

The solution I found was that you have to set **always-use-location-entry** to **false** in BOTH `gconf-editor` AND `dconf-editor`.

If either one of these has always-use-location-entry set to true, it will fail.

For `gconf-editor` it is found under **apps>nautilus>preferences**

See [Alvin Row's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/66941/527764) for how to change the setting in `dconf-editor`

Answer (score 0):

I had to install dconf-tools and change setting 'always-use-location-entry' in org.gnome.nautilus.preferences to False via dconf-editor. 
Changing the same entry in apps.nautilus.preferences with gconf-editor didn't help.