# Where are Gnome-Terminal profiles stored in the filesystem?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I created a new profile that opened with the fortune program (atp-get install fortune-mod for the download location) and set it as the profile with which to open all new terminals with so that I would get a new fortune when I opened terminal. Unfortunately I didn't know to set "exit terminal when process exits" to something else so that it wouldn't exit out almost immediately. Currently it does exit as soon as fortune exits which is nearly immediately and I need to delete the profile but i cant through the terminal "manage profiles" option because it exits too quickly to even try and open the edit menu let alone delete the profile. I need to know what directory the profile is saved to so that i can delete is manually. I tried to do a system wide search but the results of that search was tons of files and folders and I don't have time to open them all. I appreciate all help i can get. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How to import gnome-terminal profile from dconf database: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199864

Comment: As a note, the comment/link from @bartolo-otrit refers to `gnome-terminal` profiles in `dconf` (note **D**) - but in ubuntu 14, `gnome-terminal` profiles are in `gconf` (note **G**); and for `gconf`, you can look into `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/` for the profiles

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Profiles for GNOME Terminal are stored in the [GConf configuration system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor). To modify them directly, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to display the "Run a command" box, enter `gconf-editor`, and then browse to `/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles`.

Unchecking `/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/use_custom_command` should solve your problem.

An alternative method for getting out of this situation is to override the custom command by specifying another as a command-line argument, e.g. `gnome-terminal -x bash`, once again in the "Run a command" box.

Comment: The alternative method ended up being the one that worked. Thank you very much. I'd vote up but I don't have 15 reputation :(

Comment: The alternative command is also the only one that worked. In the gconf-editor, there wasn't any "use_custom_command checkbox.

Comment: @ændrük sorry for taking so long to accept. I just got a notification for this question which brought me back all these years later.

Comment: On Ubuntu 17.04, these entries aren't there in gconf-editor

Comment: Profiles for `# GNOME Terminal 3.32.1` are stored in `dconf` not `gconf`
A comment on this question seems to imply that they should be migrated over automatically to dconf, but I haven't got that to work https://askubuntu.com/questions/906137/seriously-dconf-gconf-gsettings-how-do-i-save-my-terminal-settings?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: With openSUSE Leap 15.1 and GNOME Terminal 3.26.2, profiles for GNOME Terminal can be edited using the `dconf-editor` tool and are located at `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:`

Answer (score 5):

You can also run `xterm`, another terminal emulator that is available in Ubuntu. From there you can run any commands you need.

To make it the default terminal, run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

And change the default to whatever you want.

Another approach to fix Gnome Terminal is to use Nautilus (the file manager) to delete all custom preferences:

- Navigate to `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal` (it's a hidden folder, hit `CTRL+H` to view)
- Edit the `xml` files there, or simply delete the whole `gnome-terminal` folder
- Open your Gnome Terminal again, it will be restored with factory settings

Comment: +1 for having indicated the path to the configuration files

Comment: @XavierStuvw: please note that since then Gnome Terminal switched from GConf to DConf, so those paths are not valid anymore since at least Ubuntu 18.04+

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and can find precisely `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal`. Perhaps because I use Unity as desktop manager?

Comment: @XavierStuvw: Maybe that is a leftover from previous installs. Have you upgraded to 20.04 from, say, 14.04 or 16.04? I'm am sure Gnome Terminal does not _use_ that path anymore in 18.04, and I still use Unity DE too. You might test and create/edit some terminal profiles and see if those changes are actually saved there. They probably won't.