# gnome-terminal - restoring of config for profiles

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, system-settings, gconf

Where are the profiles for gnome-terminal stored on the filesystem?

I recently restored my home folder from backup on a new ubuntu installation, but the profiles for gnome-terminal were not restored.
I've still got access to the root of the filesystem from my previous ubuntu installation, and would like to pull the profiles out of that from wherever they are stored?

---

This is similar to [Where are Gnome-Terminal profiles stored in the filesystem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72684/)

However the solution to that specifies using gconf-editor, which I've tried but which only allows me to modify the current setup.

Comment: 5 years later and have the same problem again :where-is-my-life:

Answer (score 0):

I've determined that my desired profiles live in `/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/`

However the version of gnome-settings that I'm running (3.32.1) uses `dconf` rather than `gconf` to store the settings (dconf inconveniently stores to disk in a binary file @ `~/.config/dconf/user`

gnome-settings is supposed to migrate over automatically if there's nothing in the new settings (according to @egmont at [Seriously, dconf, gconf, gsettings... How do I save my terminal settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906137/))

So first step is to backup dconf:
`cp ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.backup-`date +%Y-%m-%d``

Then verify that `/org/terminal/legacy/profiles/` doesn't actually contain anything, using `dconf-editor` (might need an install)

Then we can reset with:
`dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/`

Will see if that fixes it for me...

... nope, I had to manually inspect the old .gconf xml files to copy over each field of the profile.

Answer (score -2):

1 - To get started, press Ctrl + Alt + F1 from your desktop.

2 - Then login with your username and password

```
$ sudo rm -r .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
$ sudo shutdown -r
```

next time dont backup before trying to reset

Comment: What do you mean by 'reset'?
You don't give an explanation for why I'd remove those folders.

Comment: Seems like an evil-doer trying to ruin people's day.   Don't do what they say.