# How can I switch to other icon sets in Unity without using the Gnome Tweak Tool

Tags: 11.10, unity, icons, customization

I recently downloaded and installed the Faenza icon set on my laptop (through its creators ppa). In order to be able to use it, though, I had to install the Gnome Tweak Tool as well, which comes bundled with the Gnome-shell. The thing is, I have no intention of using the Gnome-shell.

Is there a simpler way of customizing icons in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install gconf-editor.

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

Then, open gconf-editor and go to desktop/gnome/interface and change the value of 
"icon_theme" from ubuntu-mono-dark to Faenza or Faenza-Darker.

- [How do I use the gconf editor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor)

Comment: To make changes in gconf-editor, do I have to open it via the terminal with gksudo?

Comment: No. Just use Alt+F2 and type gconf-editor. No sudo privileges are needed.