# How do I stop the mouse from "sticking" to the screen edges with multiple monitors?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable mouse magnet on middle edge with multi monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109338/how-do-i-disable-mouse-magnet-on-middle-edge-with-multi-monitors)

My mouse always hangs when moving it from one screen to the other, is there a possibility to disable this?