# Why multi-monitor support doesn't permit to move Launcher in 12.04?

Tags: launcher, multiple-monitors, 12.04

Ubuntu 12.04 brings some significant improvements to multi-monitor support, it permits to see Launcher on every monitor.

I have two monitor and Launcher compares on the left of both monitors, but **launcher in the middle would cause problems for me.**

I want launcher for each monitor: only if the user can choose the position of the launcher separately for both monitors.

For me, the best solution is: **left monitor-launcher left, right monitor-launcher right.**

*Is there any technical reason for make it not customizable?*

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/poll-multi-monitor-launchers-in-ubuntu-12-04/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well! I personally thought it could be a wrong design in an extended desktop where in the middle of the desktop, a launcher is present.
Yet, notice that the launcher has new settings :

[image: Ubuntu 12.04 Appearance settings]

The reveal sensitivity allows you to adjust how much the launcher is sensitive to your mouse crossing. The higher, the more you have to push the mouse against the launcher to reveal it.
While auto-hide is activated, and about 27 % of reveal sensitivity, you can surf your mouse from the left external monitor to the right one or the opposite, easily without accidently revealing the launcher.
Check the poll, if you want to vote for this option.

[Launcher Poll](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/poll-multi-monitor-launchers-in-ubuntu-12-04/)

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. He wants to move launcher into different areas of different screens.

Comment: I understood it. Instead of answering = "Technically, it is not yet possible to implement, because the design team did not expect this possibility before 12.10". I wanted to give an alternative.
It is actually impossible to move the launcher to any side. Forcing it, will cause many issues and this is not wanted in 12.04 LTS. That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

One good reason is that it's very difficult to implement properly. In your specific case, it wouldn't be too difficult. But what if I use three or four monitors, with three in a row and one below that row?

```
Screen_1    Screen_2    Screen_3
            Screen_4
```

Now, what would the configuration look like? You cannot make a good design by considering one situation at a time. You need to consider all the situations and make something that works well in non-homogenous landscapes as well. But we also wouldn't want a highly complicated configuration tool just to move the launcher, right?

The movable launcher thing is a much more complicated topic than you might expect before you start trying to come up with actual solutions to provide it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but an highly complicated configuration tool? I'm thinking about a little tool that visualize all monitors and the launchers position in every monitor, on the left by default. With a drag'n drop i move the launchers position in every monitor.

Comment: What happens when you take a coffee break, come back and the PC has been occupied so you have to choose one with another layout? Will you have to reconfigure the desktop? I'm obviously not saying that it can't be done. It will be fixed somehow. The question is what the best solution is and how much time the core developers have to do it.