# How can I fix the Sticky Cursor grabbed by Unity on Dual monitor setup?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, 12.04, cursor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable mouse magnet on middle edge with multi monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109338/how-do-i-disable-mouse-magnet-on-middle-edge-with-multi-monitors)

I was able to get a dual monitor setup working in 12.04 beta release recently, using the Nvidia proprietary drivers. So far it has been working well with only minor "out of the box" issues to workaround.

The only issue/annoyance that I am experiencing is the multiple Unity Panels (one on each screen). I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to change that right now, but what is happening is if the cursor is moving slowly enough near the Panel in the center of the desktop (just at transition to the two monitors), the Panel grabs the cursor and makes it "sticky". If I am moving the cursor quickly enough, it does not do this, and simply continues on to the next screen.

Is anyone aware of any options that may change the "stickiness" of the cursor around the Unity Panel? it makes for a rather annoying experience to have to jiggle the mouse to release the cursor from the Panel whenever I simply need something on the other screen.