# Mouse gets stuck when switching screens

Tags: ati, screen, monitor

Hi I have the latest amd drivers, and 3 monitors setup. When moving the mouse from one screen to another it seems like it gets stuck, and I have to keep moving it for it to finally switch, its really odd, does anybody know a quick fix?

Example: [image]

(the black is the other screen and the pattern is the other screen)

If I move the mouse fast enough it dosen't seems to happen.

Answer (score 2):

See identical question: [How do I disable mouse magnet on middle edge with multi monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109338/how-do-i-disable-mouse-magnet-on-middle-edge-with-multi-monitors)

System Settings - Displays. Uncheck the box that says "Sticky edges".

[image]