# Dual Desktop Setup / Extended. Mouse gets stuck at edges if it does not have same resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse

If I have two monitors running in extended mode that have different pixel heights the mouse gets stuck at the edge between the two monitors if the mouse is below or above the edge of the second monitor. I can see that it makes sense to have the mouse travel at the same pixel during the transition. For me it would make more sense to let it travel at the same relative height. So that on the transition if I was 10% away from the top corner, I end up 10% away from the top corner after switching the mouse pointer from screen A to screen B.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

you can check this answer.

[How do I disable mouse magnet on middle edge with multi monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109338/how-do-i-disable-mouse-magnet-on-middle-edge-with-multi-monitors)

In case you are using Nvidia, ensure that a primary monitor is set using "Nividia X Server settings".

Cheers.
Senthil Gopal

Comment: Good idea, however that is not what i wanted to achieve, this only solves the stopping at the edges, what i want is to have the upper and lower borders of the two monitors aligned virtually even though their pixel amounts differ