# dual monitors w/ different workspaces?

Tags: 10.04, multiple-monitors, monitor, workspaces, external-monitor

I have two monitors connected by vga, but both are showing the same workspace. I want to know how to fix this problem and get back to having separate workspaces on each monitor

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/109338/how-do-i-disable-mouse-magnet-on-middle-edge-with-multi-monitors

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect the cable, then put it back in after a few minutes. It'll go back to normal

Comment: This is not really a definitive answer.  The problem is that the displays are set to mirror.  This is set in System Settings --> Displays and uncheck the mirror option.  In cases were a proprietary driver module is being used that module may have it's own configuration program eg: nvidia-settings for the nvidia-current module.