# How do I properly configure my screen edges to be non-sticky?

Tags: multiple-monitors, window-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable mouse magnet on middle edge with multi monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109338/how-do-i-disable-mouse-magnet-on-middle-edge-with-multi-monitors)

I find the sticky edges feature to be quite annoying.  I'm using dual monitors and turned sticky edges off, however, when I pan the mouse from one monitor to the other, the mouse snaps to the edge.  The only way to get the cursor to move from one monitor to the other is to move the mouse swiftly - but this creates less control for me, and is rather annoying.

I'm noticing with sticky edges off, I'm easily to move my cursor from the my left (primary) monitor to the second monitor.  However, the cursor sticks when moving the cursor from the right monitor back to the left.

Has anyone else encountered this issue, and is there a fix for it?

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Also, after you set it, try logging out and back in.