# Why does Edge Resistance always turn back on in CompizConfig settings manager?

Tags: 13.04, compiz, multiple-monitors

Running Ubuntu 13.04. I'm trying to turn off Edge Resistance for multiple monitors, and it keeps turning itself back on! It seems to be triggered by mouse movement, and sometimes takes a second or two to re-activate itself.

I've made a recording of it here: https://mediacru.sh/KfaednVYJ0CH

Any ideas why it's doing this and how to turn of Edge Resistance permanently?

Comment: what you have on "Workarounds -> Window stickyness" ?

Comment: also, this may be useful http://askubuntu.com/a/109744/47044

Comment: @geoh "Window stickyness" in Workarounds is unchecked https://mediacru.sh/jFjP9VxWjmY9

Comment: well I guess you can try to check it, and try again ?