# How can I enable edge stop velocity in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors

In 12.04, one of the settings enabled by default was "edge stop velocity", which helped keep the mouse on one screen of a multi-monitor setup unless you pushed a bit harder to get the mouse onto the other screen. This seems to be disabled by default in 14.04. How can I enable this feature?

I couldn't find the setting in the Unity Tweak Tool or the dconf editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable it (if using Unity which should be the default) by running:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-capture-mouse true
```

Then, to customize how fast/hard you need to move the mouse to jump between displays:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/stop-velocity 20
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/overcome-pressure 1
```

Note that this only works if you have the Unity launcher on all the screens and you can reset to that state by running:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/num-launchers 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it is different in 14.04.  Done though display settings.

[image]

[How do I disable mouse magnet on middle edge with multi monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109338/how-do-i-disable-mouse-magnet-on-middle-edge-with-multi-monitors)