# How to enable sticky edges in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, configuration, settings

I upgraded 16.04 to 18.04 LTS.
How can I re-enable sticky edges in the new `gnome`? I cannot find anything in settings or tweak configuration...

Comment: Having same issue. Did you find a way to do this on ubuntu 18?

Comment: @membersound (although a bit late) hopefully my answer below would work,  Regards

Comment: @membersound 
 do you have a multiple monitor setup?  If so, how are they "layed" out?

Comment: I think these might be useful and address your issue.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122331/mouse-snagging-on-autohidden-vertical-dock-between-monitors
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140789/18-04-problem-moving-mouse-cursor-between-monitors

Comment: Hello I think these might address this issue
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140789/18-04-problem-moving-mouse-cursor-between-monitors
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122331/mouse-snagging-on-autohidden-vertical-dock-between-monitors

Comment: Are you sure it is not working???? I don't see my mouse stopping (on 18.04 or 20.04) between screens... but when I have a window that I am dragging between them, It does seem to pause a bit... (it may very well be that my hand is doing what my eye wants to see happen, because I was staring at it so long).. i have never paid attention to the actual behavior in anything before 18.04 so i dont know if it is different from what i am seeing now... What is for sure is that the toggle is no long there on the display config gui... from reading, it looks like you can have it with compiz

Comment: Regarding bounty: see my comments below William's answer. @Crighton, I fear those links did not provide a sollution.

Comment: You might want to check out this [gnome extention](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/). That did the trick for me on 18.04

Comment: Try putting your dock on one of the middle edges of your monitors... and try toggling the dock's auto-hide... Most existing questions are how to get rid of it...

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling true
```

Regards.

EDIT: **You can also look at the dash-to-dock settings, maybe something's there that will be useful**

Comment: If this wouldn't work for some reason, please reply and explain what went wrong, I had this problem before for some time ago.

Comment: I think we are not talking about the same thing. As far as I know sticky edges means that your mouse is shortly blocked from moving to the next monitor. This is useful if your dock is on the side of the other monitor, making it easier click on(you can't accidentally move too far into the other monitor instead). I am not sure what edge-tiling is. I have enabled it but it seems to not make a difference. Dash-to-dock does not have an option as far as I can find.

Comment: I see, edge tiling has to do with dragging windows to the side of the screen and making them full screen or half the screen size automatically. This is something different.

Comment: See the top answer here for sticky edges: https://askubuntu.com/questions/119281/what-is-the-function-of-the-sticky-edges-on-off-setting-in-displays

Comment: Ah I see, the second answer says the first answer is wrong. That's fairly unfortunate. For the bounty I'm looking for the functionality I described before :(

Comment: @AartStuurman Hot corners is not the same thing right?

Comment: No, that is something different :)

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for : https://askubuntu.com/questions/465014/how-can-i-enable-edge-stop-velocity-in-14-04

Comment: @AartStuurman Oh Okay;  Shall I add it to my answer?

Comment: It is not a solution, but it better describes what I'm looking for.