# Mouse weirdly sticking to the right edge of screen

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I'm a total noob when it comes to ubuntu and I just installed it for the first time yesterday. I love it though and I'd like learn more about it. But i have this weird glitch or whatever you wanna call it on my laptop. When i move my mouse via the tracking pad all the way to the right, it kinda gets glued to the edge and i cant move it left immediately again. It's like there is a second screen connected and the mouse goes there, only that you can still see the edge of the mouse right there so that can't be it. Does anyone else has this problem or does anyone know how to fix that .. cause it can honestly get reallllly annoying.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: oh also i forgot to say, I'm using the 2016 version of ubuntu

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/109338/how-do-i-disable-mouse-magnet-on-middle-edge-with-multi-monitors  You might want to make sure that Sticky Edges is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your display settings:
Press `Super` (windows key) and type "system settings" and open the System Settings application. At the Topic Hardware you will find Displays. Make sure there is only one Display configured. If not you can disable a display.

Comment: okay thats a bit embarrassing ... that was actually the problem haha ... i thought it cant be a second display cause i could still see the mouse on the screen but that was actually it haha .. thanks a lot