# Configure sticky edges

Tags: unity

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and like the sticky edges feature on my dual monitor setup (extra monitor on left), but would like to configure it a little *less* sticky.

Currently I have to drag about an inch beyond the edge to unstick the cursor. I'd prefer a little less, say half or a quarter of the default distance.

Is there a way to configure this "unstick" distance?

Answer (score 7):

You need to install CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Then under
Ubuntu Unity Plugin -> Experimental -> Edge Stop Velocity
you control which is the maximum velocity of your mouse that will block it's movement and stick it to the edge.

My preference for example there is "20", which allows rather fast movement of the mouse to pass through, while when being slow, it properly sticks to the edge.

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer for Ubuntu 13.10

CompizConfig Settings Manager (version: 1:0.9.10+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1) offers finer tuning, which I like. These settings make Sticky Edges much less sticky, while retaining the nice "launcher protection" behavior:

Under `Ubuntu Unity Plugin -> Launcher`

- Launcher Edge Stop Overcome Pressure: **5**
- Edge Stop Velocity: **20**
- Duration of Sticky Edge Release after Break: **1500**