# Mouse briefly halts in middle of monitor when moving down, like a sticky edge

Tags: mouse, monitor, external-monitor

Something really strange has been happening with my mouse and external monitor for about a week. As I slowly move my mouse, it halts for a little bit right in the middle of my screen. While it's stuck there, I can still move it left, right, and even back up - but not any lower. If I keep trying it eventually moves down. Also if I move my mouse to the left or right edges of my screen, it can move all the way down without problems. It is very reminiscent of a [sticky edge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119281/what-is-the-function-of-the-sticky-edges-on-off-setting-in-displays).

What's strange is that, this only happens with my external monitor, and not my laptop's built-in display. I have tried the following:

1. Turn my laptop off and then back on.
2. Disconnect and then reconnect my mouse.
3. Totally disable sticky-edges.
4. Turn my monitor off and back on.
5. Change every setting for my monitor in `Settings->Display`.

---

- **Ubuntu version**: 18.04.03 LTS
- **Computer**: HP Notebook 15-bs1xx
- **Mouse**: HP X3000 Wireless Mouse
- **External Monitor**: ViewSonic VA2259-SMH 22 Inch