# Prevent mouse pointer from going between monitors when in a corner of a monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, mouse-pointer

This is a feature that i found on windows but i can't find anything like this on Linux.

I have multiple monitors and each of them had its own taskbar. Each of them has an applications menu button on the bottom left corner.

When I have only one monitor i can quickly hit it by moving the mouse cursor as far down and left as it will go.

But on multiple monitors it will instead go to a different monitor. On windows it stops at the bottom left corner and if i want to move it to another monitor i have to move it at least a pixel up and then to the other monitor.

Is there any way to get that effect on Linux? For some time my workaround was to make the bottom of the monitor on the right be set a few pixels below the one on the left but that's not very convenient when it doesn't align with the physical layout of my monitors.

Comment: This may still work (can't test ATM): https://askubuntu.com/questions/119281/what-is-the-function-of-the-sticky-edges-on-off-setting-in-displays

Comment: After some research it appears that this feature was removed in more recent GNOME, sorry for that.

Comment: Try a different DE.  You can try out different Ubuntu flavors by creating installation media and booting the USB and selecting "Try Ubuntu". This way you don't have to make changes to your installed system. GNOME is not very good for allowing the end user to make significant tweaks to the appearance and performance of the DE.  GNOME devs designed the desktop to be consistent and easy to use and have stripped the majority of abilities to customize.  https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

Comment: I would be interested in any DE that has that feature, and I would actually prefer it to not be gnome