# How to remove docky anchor icon?

Tags: docky

I can find answers all around the Internet for doing it with `gconf-editor` in older versions of Ubuntu, but I can't find the answer for doing it with `dconf-editor` in latest release.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 12.04 you still can and have to use **gconf-editor**.

[image: Install via the software center]

When installed, run it and navigate to `apps` > `docky-2` > `Docky` > `Items` > `DockyItem`. There uncheck "ShowDockyItem". Restart Docky.

- [How do I use the gconf editor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor)