# Customize terminal size without launching terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, gconf

I changed my terminal size to a very large number and now the terminal keeps flickering at when launched and the menu on upper-left corner doesn't show up(my machine is Ubuntu 12.04)

Is there any way I can change my terminal size without launching it?

I've been looking for solutions and someone mentioned about `gconf.xml` file but in my `./gconf/apps` folder there's no such folder called `gnome-terminal`

Comment: Do you have an icon on your Desktop to launch the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install gconf-editor:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

then you can find the settings here:

[image]

Set `use_custom_default_siz` to `false`.

Above in this window you will also find the two size values if you only want to change this:

[image]

You can also change the settings from commandline or create a script-file with:

```
gconftool --type Boolean --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/use_custom_default_size false
```

and execute it, you do not need the terminal-window to run a script-file.

More info about Gconf: [How do I use the gconf editor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor)

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNOME Classic, right mouse click on the terminal icon, select "Properties" and set the command to `gnome-terminal --geometry=80x24` .

If you have Unity, you can create a launcher with this command in that way:

[How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)