# How to get the docky on an other side from terminal

Tags: command-line, software-sources

I am customizing an os an i wanted to get the docky on the side from the terminal! Is There an way for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to [Docky](https://launchpad.net/docky), you can use gconf-editor for that. Press `Alt+F2` and type in `gconf-editor` to bring up the Gnome configuration editor. If it is not installed, type:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

in a terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+T`).

You can then navigate to `Apps -> Gnome Do -> Preferences -> Docky -> Utilities -> Dock Preferences`(or whatever the path may be) and you should be able to select the "Position" item and change it to whichever position you like.

EDIT: I noticed that you want to be able to do this from the command line, you can use `gconftool-2` in much the same way. e.g.

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/docky-2/Docky/Interface/DockPreferences/Dock1/Position --type=string Top
```

(The path may be different on Ubuntu, as I'm currently running Arch and don't have access to an Ubuntu machine)

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/05/docky-move-it-to-top-of-desktop-add.html)

Source 2, find some cool information on using GConf [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/17278/423973).

Comment: Please edit the path for gconftool-2 if you are on Ubuntu and know the correct path for the Docky position setting.