# How do I fix desktop size? (see image)

Tags: 14.04, unity, display, icons

I tried installing `kubuntu-desktop` for RDP.  However it changed my Unity desktop a bit and I didn't know it was loading masses of other apps.

So I removed it and it left the desktop changes including too large icons and text. When I went to change the size, my mouse "jumped" and set it to 2x size. Before I could click it and resize it smaller again, the whole display changed and I was left with only a fraction of my desktop on the two displays.

What you see in the image below is actually a screenshot of both monitors.  You can see the center between the monitors where the task bars are different sizes. The Displays window actually crosses the two monitors.

[image: Desktop Screenshot]

As you can see, I can't reach the control to change the setting in Displays.

I guess I need to make the change in the terminal.

Any suggestions?

---

Added:

I tried logging out and back in, and restarting.  KDE desktop and xfce both work with small text and icons.  But Gnome flashback  compiz and metacity, and Ubuntu all have the oversized screens.

Comment: Press ALT and hold it and try to move the window upwards so that you can reach the control.

Comment: @Harris can you post this as an answer? I am certain that this in an actual solution.

Comment: @Harris --- Post it as an answer!  It is the answer.  Thank you and bless you!

Comment: Please do not added "solved" or some such to the question. Marking an answer as accepted is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press ALT and hold it and try to move the window upwards so that you can reach the controls.

Answer (score 0):

reinstalling unity will do it for you.

you can do it by going to a terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>  then copy past this to it.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

this should solve your problem because KDE have broken your unity,

Comment: I doubt that such a dramatic action is required to fix this. You basically suggest reinstalling half the system when simply moving the window up solves it.

Comment: You can't move the window up.. Did you see the image, that's 2 full screens it overlaps.  it is already at the top of the screen and at minimum size.

Comment: I tried the suggestion about reinstalling unity and desktop.  It didn't work.  

I need to edit the config file but I don't know what it is.

Comment: go here for how to edit it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor